# Squid Proxy not work after trying to use the dstdom_regex type

Tags: squid

I have tried to allow the Windows Update Servers in my Squid config file but i receive a error after restarting.

My Config:

```
acl windowsUpdates dstdomain windowsupdate.microsoft.com
acl windowsUpdates dstdom_regex .+\.windowsupdate\.microsoft\.com$
acl windowsUpdates dstdom_regex .+\.update\.microsoft\.com$
acl windowsUpdates dstdom_regex .+\.windowsupdate\.com$
acl windowsUpdates dstdomain download.microsoft.com
acl windowsUpdates dstdomain wustat.windows.com
acl windowsUpdates dstdomain ntservicepack.microsoft.com
acl windowsUpdates dstdomain go.microsoft.com

http_access allow windowsUpdates
```

The error i receive from "systemctl status squid.service"

```
Feb 05 10:18:37 (hidden) squid[22992]: Bungled /etc/squid/squid.acl.config line 2: acl windo
Feb 05 10:18:37 (hidden) squid[22998]: Bungled /etc/squid/squid.acl.config line 2: acl windo
Feb 05 10:18:37 (hidden) squid[22975]:  * FATAL: Bungled /etc/squid/squid.acl.config line 2:
```

Why the dstdom_regex not work. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one acl can only one type of selector `dstdomain` or `dstdom_regex` be set.
I have changed the name of the acl with type of `dstdom_regex` to windowsUpdatesRE and it works.